# Let $\alpha$ be a complex number. Show that if $(1+z)^{\alpha}$ is taken as $e^{\alpha Log(1+z)}$, then for $|z|<1$

Tags: complex-analysis, binomial-coefficients

Let $\alpha$ be a complex number. Show that if $(1+z)^{\alpha}$ is taken as $e^{\alpha Log(1+z)}$, then for $|z|<1$

$(1+z)^\alpha=1+\frac{1}{\alpha}+\frac{\alpha (\alpha -1)}{1\cdot2}z^2+\frac{\alpha( \alpha-1)(\alpha-2)}{1\cdot2\cdot3}z^3+...$

I want to find Taylor series of $e^{\alpha Log(1+z)}$.

I know $\frac{d^jLog(z)}{dz^j}=(-1)^{j+1}(j-1)!z^{-j}$

So, $(e^{\alpha Log(1+z)})^{(n)}=(e^{\alpha Log(1+z)})*(\alpha Log(1+z))^{(n)}=(e^{\alpha Log(1+z)})*\alpha (-1)^{j+1}(j-1)!(1+z)^{-j}$ 
Let $z=0$, it is euqal to $\alpha(-1)^{j+1} (j-1)!$
. The coefficient of jth term is $\frac{f^{n}(0)}{j!}=\frac{\alpha (-1)^{j+1}}{j}$.   I cannot get the binomial coefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to deduce the [binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series). I like to derive it as follows:

Let $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$. We want to find the Taylor series for $$(1+z)^\alpha:=e^{\alpha Log(1+z)},\ z\in\mathbb{D}=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|<1\}.$$ Here $Log$ denotes the principal branch of the complex logarithm (which is holomorphic in $\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}_{\leq0}$). Denote
$$
f_\alpha(z)=(1+z)^\alpha,\ z\in\mathbb{D}.
$$
This function is holomorphic (in $\mathbb{D}$) so it has a Taylor series around $0$. To compute it notice that
$$
f_\alpha'(z)=\frac{\alpha}{1+z}f_\alpha(z)=\alpha f_{\alpha-1}(z),
$$
from where we deduce
$$
f^{(k)}_\alpha(z)=\alpha(\alpha-1)\cdots(\alpha-k+1)f_{\alpha-k}(z)
$$
for $k\geq1$. Evaluating at $z=0$ we obtain $f^{(k)}_\alpha(0)=\alpha(\alpha-1)\cdots(\alpha-k+1)$, and so
$$
f_\alpha(z)=(1+z)^\alpha=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)\cdots(\alpha-k+1)}{k!}z^k,\ \ z\in\mathbb{D}.
$$

It is customary to denote this coefficients by $\left(\begin{array}{c}\alpha\\ k\end{array}\right)$, so
$$
(1+z)^\alpha=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\begin{array}{c}\alpha\\ k\end{array}\right)z^k
$$
accordingly with the $\alpha\in\mathbb{N}$-case.

Comment: I know your proof is true. However, I find the nth derivative of $e^{\alpha Log(1+z)}$ directively, and then to find the Taylor series. Where is my mistake?

Comment: @CZX You're differenciating wrong; it is not true that $(e^{\alpha Log(1+z)})^{(j)}=e^{\alpha Log(1+z)}\alpha Log(1+z)^{(j)}$ if $j>1$. For example with $j=2$ you have $(e^{\alpha Log(1+z)})''=(e^{\alpha Log(1+z)}\alpha Log(1+z)')'\neq e^{\alpha Log(1+z)}\alpha Log(1+z)''$.

Comment: I found this stupid mistake. Thank you!

Comment: @CZX I was wondering if maybe you didn't accepted my answer cause there was still some unclear issue and after seeing your profile I've noticed that you haven't accepted many answers that seemed pretty good. I think you should accept them if they were satisfactory. It's not about points, It's about helping the community to grow, and to get the question back on top so the rest of the community can validate and benefit from it. Please consider it.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: @CZX Glad to hear it, you're welcome:)